# format a number to a character with css

Tags: css

I'm working with a list of numbers in a table, specifically golf scores.  And I want to replace occurrences of '0' with 'E'.  I was doing this at the application level but the javascript I'm currently using to do some sorting gets very confused finding a letter in the middle of all the numbers.  I look at it as a presentation problem and was hoping there's a css based solution.

Comment: you got something to look at? pretty sure there is

Comment: The closes CSS gets is with it's `:before` and `:after` pseudo selectors, along with `content: ""`. You can't manipulate strings with CSS - it's not what it's for. If CSS _could_ be used in this case, then you could easily argue that it could be used for much more than layout and styling.

Comment: I figured out a different solution (basically forced the sort to numeric regardless of the contents).  But the contents in question are a group of table cells containing:
12
<span class='under'>-11</span>
34
E
23
E
12
<span class='under'-3</span>

etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really. There was an effort to allow for a `:contains()` selector but that got removed.

Here's a sneaky way to get the effect you want, though I suspect **what you really need to do is fix the way your JavaScript executes sorts**.

So what you can do is add an attribute to your list, I've called mine `data-score` and replicate the scores.

Then using the CSS attribute match selectors, you add some content, the "E", and alongside that you make the "E" black, and the original content ("O") white.

```
<style type="text/css">
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}
/* turn the "0" white */
li[data-score="0"] {
    color: #fff;
}
/* make an E, in black */
li[data-score="0"]:before {
    content: "E";
    color: #000;
}
</style>

<ul>
    <li data-score="100">100</li>
    <li data-score="0">0</li>
    <li data-score="10">10</li>
    <li data-score="5">5</li>
    <li data-score="100">100</li>
</ul>
```

Which will display as:

```
100
E
10
5
100
```

With the "0" really being there, but not visible.

Read more about: [`:before`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#gen-content) selector, [`content`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#propdef-content), [data attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes).

Additionally, if you just plain output the "E" for a "0", and use data attributes for the sort, you can avoid the CSS hackery I'm suggesting.

Comment: Even though this is practically heresy for us CSS puritans, it's a neat solution =)

Comment: It's a real fun hack! It sounds like the root problem is existing sorting implementation of the JavaScript. Most datatables implementations allow you to specify either hidden data to accomplish sorts or the ability to specify a comparator function that you can customize so it matches your data (like accounting for missing fields or "N/A"). Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

There isn't, unfortunately. You'll have to do it with JavaScript or on the server side.

Comment: actually, you can replace the contents using pseudo selectors

Comment: Can you give an example of a replacement?